# Javascript - Problems with Loop with Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iframe

I have the following code that when working correctly should open link 1 in the iframe, wait 3 seconds, then open link 2 in the iframe, wait 3 seconds, etc..

Currently it's skipping straight to the last value in the array (the last link).

Any JS expert takers?

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

 <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><br />
 <a href="http://www.thinkgeek.com">ThinkGeek</a><br />
 <a href="http://www.themetapicture.com">The Meta Picture</a>

 <iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="myid" name="main" width="1024" height="768">
 </iframe>

 <script>
 function getLinksArray() {
     for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
         var linx = document.links[i].href;

         // create a closure for each loop iteration
         (function(linx) {
           setTimeout(function() {
             openLinks(linx);
           }, 3000);
         }(linx));

     }
 }

 function openLinks(link) {
 document.getElementById("myid").src = link;
 }

 window.onload = getLinksArray();
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The loop will create the timeouts super quick so the first one will wait 3 seconds only to have the 3rd be milliseconds behind. Open links should create the next timeout.

Comment: All of your events would go off in three seconds — multiply 3000 by the current iteration count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure something like this should do the trick, without creating longer and longer delays. Haven't performance tested both though, so can't say which is best - just wanted to make sure you were aware of another option.

```
var linx = document.links;
(function loadLink(i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
        document.getElementById("myid").src = linx[i].href;
        if(linx[++i])
        {
            loadLink(i);
        }
    }, 3000)
})(0);
```

Comment: Haha, got so distracted while writing my answer someone else posted a very similar one before me.. ah well, still a different approach!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `3000 * i` as your delay, otherwise all execute after 3000ms (3 seconds). and since they're executed serially, the last one is the one that's noticed.

```
// ...
setTimeout(function(){
  // ...
}, 3000 * i);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simply make the iteration itself timed:

```
function loadLink(i) {
    document.getElementById("myid").src = document.links[i].href;
    if (i < document.links.length) {
        window.setTimeout(function() { loadLink(i+1) }, 3000);
    }
}

window.onload = loadLink(0);
```